# Customise existing software with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to customize `sharetronix` with the Yii farmework.

I'm wondering if it is affordable to customize non-Yii software with the Yii framework? is there any way to customize `sharetronix` by a more suitable framework than Yii?

Comment: Is not clear what you are asking. Please give us more details. Yii as a framework, allow to build software on his standards and architecture. You can extend yii with their structure or use yii together with other software's (include yii in other programs non Yii). Yii is not an Ide or similar

Comment: thanks for response but I know all about what you said. my question is: `sharetronix` is not based on Yii framework. i want to extend it with Yii framework.is that logical way to customize `sharetronix` (a system which it's framework is not YII) with YII ?

Comment: Yes, you can include yii on any external project.